# $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ is not dense in $\mathcal L^\infty(\mathbb R ^n)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I'm having some difficulties in manipulating the space $\mathcal L^\infty(\mathbb R ^n)$, and I want to show that $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ is not dense in $\mathcal L^\infty(\mathbb R ^n)$, but I can't find a counterexample or even a good reference of the demonstration; Any hint or reference would be very helpful. Thank you for your time

Comment: What is $C_c$ continous with compact support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you approximate the constant function $1$, which belongs to $L^\infty$, by continuous functions of compact support?

Comment: if we proceed by absurd, I think the answer is No. Consider $f=1$ and Suppose there exist a sequence $(\phi_n)_n\subset C_c(\mathbb R^n)$, such that $\phi_n\to f\ as\ n\to\infty$ then $\|f\|_\infty\leq \|f-\phi_n+\phi_n\|_\infty\leq \|f-\phi_n\|_\infty+\|\phi_n\|_\infty$ and since the sequence has a compact the support then $\|\phi_n\|_\infty=0$ so $\|f-\phi_n|_\infty\geq \|f\|_\infty =1$ absurd when $n\to\infty$; is that correct ?

Comment: No, it is not true that $\lVert\phi_n\rVert_\infty=0$. In any case, you can proceed simply by showing that the distance between your $f=1$ and any $\phi\in C_c$ is at least one.

Comment: Ah! Okay, I'll try simply to show that, thank you

Comment: (I've replaced the word "constant [support]" by the word "compact [support]". I guess that was the intended word.)